# Best way to handle case where same code must run either immediately or after a promise resolved

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

Depending on a certain condition `x`, I need to perform a redirect either right now or after a promise `asyncFunction` resolved:

```
if (x) {
  await asyncFunction();
  redirectToA();
}
redirectToA();
```

That's quite ugly though. Is there a way to simplify this code so that `redirectToA();` appears only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could simply do this:

```
if (x) {
  await asyncFunction();
}
redirectToA();
```

This is an example showing you that the `redirectToA()` will wait:

```js
async function asyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, 3000)
  })
}

function redirectToA() {
  document.getElementById('status').innerText = "Redirected"
}


(async function() {
  // your code is here
  if (true) {
    await asyncFunction()
  }
  redirectToA()
})()
```

```html
<p id="status">
  Running
</p>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `if (x) { ... }` and `redirectToA()` run asynchronously regardless of what's inside the `{ ... }` block?

Comment: I don't think so. If the x returns false, the body should be skipped, so the async code never runs. There is nothing asynchronous outside the if body, or? am I missing something ?

Comment: But if `x` returns true will `redirectToA()` run only after `asyncFunction()` resolves, and if so why?

Comment: As far as I know, as long as you use await in front of your async call, the rest of the execution of the current executing code will wait for the promise to resolve, and only then continue. We can try this with some timeout easily but I am not at the PC currently

Comment: @drake035 added an example demonstrating what I just said.

Comment: @ajobi `redirectToA()` will be executed immediately if `x` is falsey, I'm curious why you think it may be otherwise?

Comment: No no, that's a misunderstanding, I know it will be executed immediately if x is falsey. But that's what the op needs, see: "Depending on a certain condition x, I need to perform a redirect either right now or after a promise asyncFunction resolved"

Answer (score 0):

It may not be an issue but I would be inclined to call `redirectToA()` at nextTick+ under both conditions.

```
await (x ? asyncFunction() : Promise.resolve());
redirectToA();
```

Thus, you are better guaranteed consistent redirect behaviour and may possibly benefit from less testing.